# How to deploy Django + React project to hosting platform?

Tags: reactjs, django, heroku, deployment, netlify

I used Django as backend and React as frontend.
I want to know how to deploy this project to hosting platform such as heroku, netlify, etc.
Can I deploy this project to one domain?
Or should I have to use two doamins - one for Django and one for React?

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to find the answer to this?

You will need to deploy two separate apps. I presume, you have been making axios/fetch calls between the frontend and backend on localhost? It will work just like that, except instead of localhost, the calls go to where ever the backend is deployed.

Now deploying is a beast of its own. Good luck!